# Concatenate values in ascending order using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, concatenation

I have a DataFrame with some columns. The columns are: A1, A2, A3. I would like to create a new column let's name it 'CON'. The new column is a string concatenated from A1, A2, A3 with a separator. The concatenation is sorted by the values of the values of the columns.

For example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A1' : ['b1', 'a1', 'a2'], 
    'A2' : ['b2', 'a3', 'b1'],
    'A3' : ['c2', 'a2', 'a1']
  })

data['CON'] = sortedConcat(data['A1'], data['A2'], data['A3'])
```

The expected result is:

```
   A1  A2  A3       CON
0  b1  b2  c2  b1-b2-c2
1  a1  a3  a2  a1-a2-a3
2  a2  b1  a1  a1-a2-b1
```

I have tried to loop the whole dataframe row by row, extracted the values to a list, sorted it and finally created the result. It was quite slow and resulted an ugly code. Is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) over `axis=1` in combination with `list comprehension`:

```
data['CON'] = ['-'.join(x) for x in np.sort(data, axis=1)]

   A1  A2  A3       CON
0  b1  b2  c2  b1-b2-c2
1  a1  a3  a2  a1-a2-a3
2  a2  b1  a1  a1-a2-b1
```

---

**Details**:
`np.sort` gives us a sorted array:

```
np.sort(data, axis=1)

array([['b1', 'b2', 'c2'],
       ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
       ['a1', 'a2', 'b1']], dtype=object)
```

---

**Edit** to only select certain column, you can use `loc` or `iloc`, `loc` is label based indexing (so with column names), `iloc` is position based indexing.

```
# Random columns
list_cols = ['col1', 'col5', 'col9', 'col12']
data['CON'] = ['-'.join(x) for x in np.sort(data[list_cols], axis=1)]

# First 10 columns
data['CON'] = ['-'.join(x) for x in np.sort(data.iloc[:, :10], axis=1)]

# Column 4 - 14
data['CON'] = ['-'.join(x) for x in np.sort(data.iloc[:, 4:14], axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you! np.sort looks terribly fast.
I have a dataframe with around 50 columns, I would like to make this concat only on 10. How can I define these columns?

Comment: data['CON'] = ['-'.join(x) for x in np.sort(data[['A2', 'A3']], axis=1)]

Comment: I made an edit and added 3 examples on how to select certain columns @pvoj

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `join` and sorted:

```
data['CON'] = data.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

Alternative with list comprehension:

```
data['CON'] = ['-'.join(sorted(x)) for x in data.values]
```

---

```
print (data)
   A1  A2  A3       CON
0  b1  b2  c2  b1-b2-c2
1  a1  a3  a2  a1-a2-a3
2  a2  b1  a1  a1-a2-b1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
data['CON'] = data.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

---

```
print(data)

 A1  A2  A3       CON
0  b1  b2  c2  b1-b2-c2
1  a1  a3  a2  a1-a2-a3
2  a2  b1  a1  a1-a2-b1
```

Comment: This is not sorted

Comment: As per user request :)